Build a Snap package using GitHub Actions
I'm trying to build the MicroK8s Snap package from the source code using snapcraft command on GitHub Actions, but it is failing at the build stage with an error:
Building snap package
You need 'multipass' set-up to build snaps: https://multipass.run.
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.

This is the part of the workflow
        # Install Snapcraft
      - name: Install Snapcraft
        uses: samuelmeuli/action-snapcraft@v3

      - name: Build Snap Package.
        run: |
          echo "Building snap package"
          cd ./microk8s-src/
          snapcraft

Is it possible to build a snap package using snapcraft in GitHub Actions?
